# How can I deal with Doctrine::find not initializing unmapped entity properties when I have created a constructor for that purpose?

Tags: php, oop, orm, doctrine-orm

I have created a Doctrine Entity, mapped various properties to database columns, and then added my own properties not mapped to any columns.  I have then initialized them via a constructor or at property declaration time.

Now I have a problem in that Doctrine fetch leaves my unmapped properties uninitialized:

```
class TheEntity
{
    /**
     * mapped to column
     *
     * @var integer @Column(name="num", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $num;

    /**
     * unmapped var, being initialized at property declaration
     * alternatively I can do it in a __construct() with the same result
     */
    private $extraVar = '0.01';
}

//initializes my non-column mapped properties 
//but does not load a record from the database
$object = new TheEntity();

//loads mapped properties but leaves unmapped one uninitialized
$object = $em->getRepository()->find($id);
```

I end up with a partially loaded object.

My solution could be to add my unmapped properties into the database, and map the propertie to columns.  But I see that as undesirable.  I could do it but that involves modifying the database.  I rather seek a solution using purely code.

I would also like to avoid hacks like `$entity->initializeUnmappedProperties()` if I can avoid them, and seek a solution that involves language facilities or Doctrine facilities first.

Despite what I have said above, ideally I am looking for an overall best solution for me so I will accept an answer that reflect best available solution.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be having good results with

```php
$object = $em->getRepository()->find($id);
$object->__construct();
```

where initialization of unmapped properties is moved to the constructor

Comment: Dennis, this will probably be your best bet since doctrine class mapping does not initialize the constructor on find. However, I'd suggest moving this behavior to an abstract repository and have your custom repositories extend it. That way you can call, `$repo->findWithConstruction($id)`, which would invoke the code in your solution.

Comment: Calling __construct is basically the same as calling initializeUnmappedProperties.  If you really need this sort of functionality then take a look at life cycle events: https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html.  But in the long run, you will be better off not having unmapped properties at all.

Comment: @Syx, thanks.  Could you give me a barebones pseudocode for this?  Or a more detailed explanation?  I have a hard time conceptualizing the abstract & custom repository pattern

Comment: @Dennis - I've added the example as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the (untested) pseudo code you requested.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyRepository")
 */
class MyEntity 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->autoPopulatedProp = 'foo';
    }
}

abstract class AbstractRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository 
{
    public function findWithConstruction($id) 
    {
        $entity = parent::find($id);
        return $entity->__construct();
    }
}

class MyRepository extends AbstractRepository {}

// Implementation
$this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('MyBundle:MyRepository')
    ->findWithConstruction($id);
```

Comment: You can also overload all repositories implicitly (without the annotation) using `setDefaultRepositoryClassName` [http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#default-repository-optional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#default-repository-optional)